# Create a Job in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dbms-scheduler

I have to create a job periodically.

But firstly I have create a simply job to learn how to create jobs in oracle, because is the first time I use a job.

It runs at systimestamp, but the job doesn't execute.

```
create or replace procedure job_test
is
begin
update table_a set value_user = 'JOB_EXECUTED' where id = 1; 
commit;
end;
/
```

Then the scheduler job

```
begin 
dbms_scheduler.create_job(
job_name => 'test_job_A',
job_type => 'stored_procedure',
job_action => 'job_test',
start_date = SYSTIMESTAMP,
enabled => true
);
end;
/
```

Then I consult the column value_user and it hasn't been updated.

```
 select * from table_A where id = 1;
```

Can anyone explain me what I am missing.

Comment: I have created a test table "table_a" with only "value_user" and "id" columns. I have then inserted one row of values (id = 1, value_user = 'test'). I have then created your  procedure and your job. I have done this in SQL developer and all is ok. When I run query "select * from table_A where id = 1;" I get (id = 1,  value_user = JOB_EXECUTED). Do you have a row in your table that has id = 1 ? I have to ask :)

Answer (score 2):

```
create table user_count (
number_of_users NUMBER(4),
time_of_day   TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_user_count AS
 v_user_count NUMBER(4);
BEGIN
 SELECT count(*)
  INTO v_user_count
 FROM v$session
 WHERE username IS NOT NULL;
 INSERT INTO user_count
 VALUES (v_user_count, systimestamp);
 commit;
 END insert_user_count;

BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM (
 program_name      => 'PROG_INSERT_USER_COUNT',
 program_action     => 'INSERT_USER_COUNT',
 program_type      => 'STORED_PROCEDURE');
END; 

BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE (
 schedule_name   => 'my_weekend_5min_schedule',
 start_date    => SYSTIMESTAMP,
 repeat_interval  => 'FREQ=MINUTELY; INTERVAL=5; BYDAY=SAT,SUN',
 end_date     => SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '30' day,
 comments     => 'Every 5 minutes');
END;

BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
  job_name     => 'my_user_count_job',
  program_name   => 'prog_insert_user_count',
  schedule_name   => 'my_weekend_5min_schedule');
END;

exec dbms_scheduler.enable('my_user_count_job’)

select * from user_count;

select job_name, status, run_duration, cpu_used
from USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS
where job_name = ‘MY_USER_COUNT_JOB’;
```

Comment: Also explain your answer on what you did and how it satisfies the OP

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your case should work but once(*provided there already exists a row with id value equals to 1*). Suppose you have an insert statement rather than an update, but doesn't repeat to populate the table with new incremented ID values.

For this, important point is to add `repeat_interval`  argument such as below :

```
begin 
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(
                            job_name => 'test_job_A',
                            job_type => 'stored_procedure',
                            job_action => 'job_test',
                            start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP,
                            enabled => true,
                            repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=5',
                            auto_drop => false,
                            comments => 'Inserts new records' 
                           );
end;
/
```

which inserts new records for each five minutes.